# Getting page content from vk.com

Tags: php, video-streaming

I would like to fetch the content of the page from vk.com.I'm using php and i've got the page contents but however its not the appropriate contents.For example when i get the contents from vk.com/video56612186_167049188 is should be getting the video details completely at the bottom but i'm getting the users video list as page content.I've noted that that the the part that i want is loaded by ajax upon click and the link on the address bar also chnages, means that i should be getting the video contents but its not the case.

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

function get_content_of_url($url){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}
$plyst  =   get_content_of_url("http://vk.com/video56612186_167049188");
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The URL is sending a redirect , so add this **`cURL`** param to your existing thing..

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: i don't think that it is send ding a redirect its just adding a part at the bottom, its that part that i want.Check my edit.

Comment: So you need the src content (link) ? or can you clarify what is your expected output ?

Comment: Check the link http://vk.com/videos56612186 .....and then click on any video. What i want is the the content that is generated when i click on the video